# Getting Sections of an API using requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to get a section of the fortnite API that is in lifeTimeStats and the kills value. I can't figure out how to just get the kills and not the whole API.

```
import requests
headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': '52f2fbde-018d-47b5-9c7d-99990c0d3507'}
url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/loopisjones'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
test = r.text
print test
```

These are the results there are too many character to enter the whole thing but I want to just get the kills from the "lifeTimeStats":

```
{
  "accountId": "649eb4a8-584e-4896-adc9-66569ee92139",
  "platformId": 3,
  "platformName": "pc",
  "platformNameLong": "PC",
  "epicUserHandle": "loopisjones",
  "stats": {
    "p2": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1111,
        "value": "1111",
        "rank": 2507075,
        "displayValue": "1,111"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 97533,
        "value": "97533",
        "rank": 279372,
        "displayValue": "97,533"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 3,
        "value": "3",
        "rank": 978112,
        "percentile": 48.0,
        "displayValue": "3"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 56,
        "value": "56",
        "rank": 577434,
        "percentile": 6.0,
        "displayValue": "56"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 176,
        "value": "176",
        "rank": 318099,
        "percentile": 3.2,
        "displayValue": "176"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.04,
        "value": "1.04",
        "rank": 1484862,
        "percentile": 42.0,
        "displayValue": "1.04"
      },
      "winRatio": {
        "label": "Win %",
        "field": "WinRatio",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.5,
        "value": "0.5",
        "rank": 1549361,
        "percentile": 61.0,
        "displayValue": "0.50"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 658,
        "value": "658",
        "rank": 277505,
        "percentile": 12.0,
        "displayValue": "658"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 680,
        "value": "680",
        "rank": 470461,
        "percentile": 18.0,
        "displayValue": "680"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.03,
        "value": "1.03",
        "rank": 1484405,
        "percentile": 41.0,
        "displayValue": "1.03"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 323.43,
        "value": "323.43",
        "rank": 1535727,
        "displayValue": "5m 23s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 148.23,
        "value": "148.23",
        "rank": 1272686,
        "percentile": 53.0,
        "displayValue": "148.23"
      }
    },
    "p10": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1200,
        "value": "1200",
        "displayValue": "1,200"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 46764,
        "value": "46764",
        "rank": 1123263,
        "displayValue": "46,764"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 3,
        "value": "3",
        "rank": 1383465,
        "percentile": 48.0,
        "displayValue": "3"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 20,
        "value": "20",
        "rank": 1438657,
        "percentile": 15.0,
        "displayValue": "20"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 56,
        "value": "56",
        "rank": 1335530,
        "percentile": 14.0,
        "displayValue": "56"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.68,
        "value": "0.68",
        "rank": 2133720,
        "percentile": 68.0,
        "displayValue": "0.68"
      },
      "winRatio": {
        "label": "Win %",
        "field": "WinRatio",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.9,
        "value": "0.9",
        "rank": 1752091,
        "percentile": 55.0,
        "displayValue": "0.90"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 347,
        "value": "347",
        "rank": 944115,
        "percentile": 30.0,
        "displayValue": "347"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 234,
        "value": "234",
        "rank": 1291960,
        "percentile": 40.0,
        "displayValue": "234"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.67,
        "value": "0.67",
        "rank": 2137868,
        "percentile": 68.0,
        "displayValue": "0.67"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 273.72,
        "value": "273.72",
        "rank": 2125448,
        "displayValue": "4m 33s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 134.77,
        "value": "134.77",
        "rank": 2058752,
        "percentile": 63.0,
        "displayValue": "134.77"
      }
    },
    "p9": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1121,
        "value": "1121",
        "rank": 2180620,
        "displayValue": "1,121"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 98339,
        "value": "98339",
        "rank": 880324,
        "displayValue": "98,339"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 8,
        "value": "8",
        "rank": 1488695,
        "percentile": 31.0,
        "displayValue": "8"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 36,
        "value": "36",
        "rank": 1240417,
        "percentile": 13.0,
        "displayValue": "36"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 80,
        "value": "80",
        "rank": 1113740,
        "percentile": 11.0,
        "displayValue": "80"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.94,
        "value": "0.94",
        "rank": 1775409,
        "percentile": 54.0,
        "displayValue": "0.94"
      },
      "winRatio": {
        "label": "Win %",
        "field": "WinRatio",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.3,
        "value": "1.3",
        "rank": 2230627,
        "percentile": 49.0,
        "displayValue": "1.30"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 603,
        "value": "603",
        "rank": 677528,
        "percentile": 14.0,
        "displayValue": "603"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 562,
        "value": "562",
        "rank": 873151,
        "percentile": 21.0,
        "displayValue": "562"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.93,
        "value": "0.93",
        "rank": 1731964,
        "percentile": 53.0,
        "displayValue": "0.93"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 221.59,
        "value": "221.59",
        "rank": 2532805,
        "displayValue": "3m 41s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 163.08,
        "value": "163.08",
        "rank": 2029616,
        "percentile": 42.0,
        "displayValue": "163.08"
      }
    },
    "curr_p2": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1111,
        "value": "1111",
        "displayValue": "1,111"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 22500,
        "value": "22500",
        "rank": 470532,
        "percentile": 26.0,
        "displayValue": "22,500"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1238303,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 16,
        "value": "16",
        "rank": 526184,
        "percentile": 6.0,
        "displayValue": "16"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 43,
        "value": "43",
        "rank": 384684,
        "percentile": 3.9,
        "displayValue": "43"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.03,
        "value": "1.03",
        "rank": 1459203,
        "displayValue": "1.03"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 149,
        "value": "149",
        "rank": 455652,
        "percentile": 19.0,
        "displayValue": "149"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 153,
        "value": "153",
        "rank": 637148,
        "percentile": 26.0,
        "displayValue": "153"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.03,
        "value": "1.03",
        "rank": 1446183,
        "percentile": 51.0,
        "displayValue": "1.03"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 70.87,
        "value": "70.87",
        "rank": 962042,
        "percentile": 39.0,
        "displayValue": "1m 10s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 151.01,
        "value": "151.01",
        "rank": 1366860,
        "percentile": 65.0,
        "displayValue": "151.01"
      }
    },
    "curr_p10": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1200,
        "value": "1200",
        "displayValue": "1,200"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 13669,
        "value": "13669",
        "rank": 1152025,
        "percentile": 42.0,
        "displayValue": "13,669"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 1,
        "value": "1",
        "rank": 1151758,
        "displayValue": "1"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 7,
        "value": "7",
        "rank": 1141708,
        "percentile": 15.0,
        "displayValue": "7"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 22,
        "value": "22",
        "rank": 903205,
        "percentile": 11.0,
        "displayValue": "22"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.75,
        "value": "0.75",
        "rank": 1887251,
        "displayValue": "0.75"
      },
      "winRatio": {
        "label": "Win %",
        "field": "WinRatio",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.0,
        "value": "1",
        "rank": 1443516,
        "percentile": 54.0,
        "displayValue": "1.00"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 96,
        "value": "96",
        "rank": 936423,
        "percentile": 35.0,
        "displayValue": "96"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 71,
        "value": "71",
        "rank": 1252315,
        "percentile": 46.0,
        "displayValue": "71"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 0.74,
        "value": "0.74",
        "rank": 1893112,
        "percentile": 71.0,
        "displayValue": "0.74"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 26.88,
        "value": "26.88",
        "rank": 2497616,
        "percentile": 91.0,
        "displayValue": "26s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 142.39,
        "value": "142.39",
        "rank": 1954451,
        "percentile": 71.0,
        "displayValue": "142.39"
      }
    },
    "curr_p9": {
      "trnRating": {
        "label": "TRN Rating",
        "field": "TRNRating",
        "category": "Rating",
        "valueInt": 1121,
        "value": "1121",
        "displayValue": "1,121"
      },
      "score": {
        "label": "Score",
        "field": "Score",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 48923,
        "value": "48923",
        "rank": 498058,
        "percentile": 8.0,
        "displayValue": "48,923"
      },
      "top1": {
        "label": "Wins",
        "field": "Top1",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 4,
        "value": "4",
        "rank": 1164590,
        "displayValue": "4"
      },
      "top3": {
        "label": "Top 3",
        "field": "Top3",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 16,
        "value": "16",
        "rank": 861117,
        "percentile": 11.0,
        "displayValue": "16"
      },
      "top5": {
        "label": "Top 5",
        "field": "Top5",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top6": {
        "label": "Top 6",
        "field": "Top6",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 38,
        "value": "38",
        "rank": 634089,
        "percentile": 7.0,
        "displayValue": "38"
      },
      "top10": {
        "label": "Top 10",
        "field": "Top10",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top12": {
        "label": "Top 12",
        "field": "Top12",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "top25": {
        "label": "Top 25",
        "field": "Top25",
        "category": "Tops",
        "valueInt": 0,
        "value": "0",
        "rank": 1,
        "displayValue": "0"
      },
      "kd": {
        "label": "K/d",
        "field": "KD",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.02,
        "value": "1.02",
        "rank": 1482777,
        "displayValue": "1.02"
      },
      "winRatio": {
        "label": "Win %",
        "field": "WinRatio",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.2,
        "value": "1.2",
        "rank": 1953805,
        "percentile": 52.0,
        "displayValue": "1.20"
      },
      "matches": {
        "label": "Matches",
        "field": "Matches",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 322,
        "value": "322",
        "rank": 188452,
        "percentile": 2.8,
        "displayValue": "322"
      },
      "kills": {
        "label": "Kills",
        "field": "Kills",
        "category": "General",
        "valueInt": 324,
        "value": "324",
        "rank": 455442,
        "percentile": 10.0,
        "displayValue": "324"
      },
      "kpg": {
        "label": "Kills Per Match",
        "field": "KPG",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 1.01,
        "value": "1.01",
        "rank": 1435682,
        "percentile": 52.0,
        "displayValue": "1.01"
      },
      "avgTimePlayed": {
        "label": "Avg Match Time",
        "field": "AvgTimePlayed",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 27.02,
        "value": "27.02",
        "rank": 2559533,
        "percentile": 91.0,
        "displayValue": "27s"
      },
      "scorePerMatch": {
        "label": "Score per Match",
        "field": "ScorePerMatch",
        "category": "General",
        "valueDec": 151.93,
        "value": "151.93",
        "rank": 2317854,
        "percentile": 64.0,
        "displayValue": "151.93"
      }
    }
  },
  "lifeTimeStats": [
    {
      "key": "Top 3",
      "value": "56"
    },
    {
      "key": "Top 5s",
      "value": "20"
    },
    {
      "key": "Top 3s",
      "value": "36"
    },
    {
      "key": "Top 6s",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "key": "Top 12s",
      "value": "56"
    },
    {
      "key": "Top 25s",
      "value": "176"
    },
    {
      "key": "Score",
      "value": "242,636"
    },
    {
      "key": "Matches Played",
      "value": "1608"
    },
    {
      "key": "Wins",
      "value": "14"
    },
    {
      "key": "Win%",
      "value": "1%"
    },
    {
      "key": "Kills",
      "value": "1476"
    },
    {
      "key": "K/d",
      "value": "0.93"
    },
    {
      "key": "Kills Per Min",
      "value": "0.2"
    },
    {
      "key": "Time Played",
      "value": "5d 2h 37m "
    },
    {
      "key": "Avg Survival Time",
      "value": "4m 34s"
    }
  ],
  "recentMatches": [
    {
      "id": 71608051,
      "accountId": "649eb4a8-584e-4896-adc9-66569ee92139",
      "playlist": "p2",
      "kills": 15,
      "minutesPlayed": 0,
      "top1": 0,
      "top5": 0,
      "top6": 0,
      "top10": 2,
      "top12": 0,
      "top25": 4,
      "matches": 16,
      "top3": 0,
      "dateCollected": "2018-03-21T12:26:33.713",
      "score": 2018,
      "platform": 3,
      "trnRating": 1111.8,
      "trnRatingChange": -9.6963567258982941
    },
    {
      "id": 71608050,
      "accountId": "649eb4a8-584e-4896-adc9-66569ee92139",
      "playlist": "p9",
      "kills": 7,
      "minutesPlayed": 0,
      "top1": 0,
      "top5": 0,
      "top6": 2,
      "top10": 0,
      "top12": 0,
      "top25": 0,
      "matches": 11,
      "top3": 0,
      "dateCollected": "2018-03-21T12:26:33.697",
      "score": 1342,
      "platform": 3,
      "trnRating": 1121.4,
      "trnRatingChange": -9.6722971885223643
    },


    ...
```

Comment: Please show the results you get from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `.json()` function of the `requests` module.

```
headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': '52f2fbde-018d-47b5-9c7d-99990c0d3507'}
url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/loopisjones'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = r.json()

for item in data['lifeTimeStats']:
    if item['key'] == 'Kills':
        print(item['value'])
```

Output:

```
1520
```